# facing attachment issue while sync with cloudant database

Tags: android, database, couchdb, cloudant

while sync with database i am facing some error from library like:-

```
E/PullStrategy: There was a problem downloading an attachment to the datastore, terminating replication
com.cloudant.sync.datastore.AttachmentNotSavedException: Actual length of 225 does not equal expected length of 0
at com.cloudant.sync.datastore.AttachmentManager.prepareAttachment(AttachmentManager.java:219)
at com.cloudant.sync.datastore.DatastoreImpl.prepareAttachment(DatastoreImpl.java:1037)
at com.cloudant.sync.replication.DatastoreWrapper.prepareAttachment(DatastoreWrapper.java:136)
at com.cloudant.sync.replication.PullStrategy.processOneChangesBatch(PullStrategy.java:386)
at com.cloudant.sync.replication.PullStrategy.replicate(PullStrategy.java:252)
at com.cloudant.sync.replication.PullStrategy.run(PullStrategy.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

please help if you know about that then.. thank you

Comment: What version of the library are you using? What server are you connecting to?

Comment: compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
this two library i am using.

Comment: Neither of those will provide the stack trace you've given. You should have an artifact with the group ID com.cloudant